# 1対多の関係の際に、attributesメソッドがつかえず、次のエラーがでます。NoMethodError: undefined method `attributes' for #Answere::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

以下のリレーションのmodelがあります。

```
class Question
  has_many :answeres
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answeres
end


class Answere
  belongs_to :question
end
```

そのような前提の中、controller内で、
@question.answeres.attributes
としようとすると、

NoMethodError: undefined method `attributes' for #Answere::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy

というエラーが出ます。

```
※  ApplicationControllerは継承しております。記号をつけると、うまく表示されないため、省略

class QuestionsController
  @question.answeres.attributes = answere_params

  private

  def answere_params
    xxxxxx
  end
end
```

1対1のリレーションの時では、attributesメソッドは使用できるのですが、今回のような1対多の関係では、どのように実装するのが一般的なのでしょうか？

なお、answere_paramsの実装は、デバッグ中に確認しており、動作は問題ありません。
期待する値が入っているのですが、それを、最終的に、answere内につめこみ保存したいです。

不足点がございましたら補足致します。

宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

`@question.answers`は `answer`のコレクションになるので、`answer` の`attributes`を取得したい場合は以下のように呼び出せば良いと思います。

```
@question.answers.first.attributes
```

また`@questions`に新しい`answer`を追加するには幾つかの方法がありますが、`build`を利用してみるはいかがでしょうか。

```
@anwser = @question.answers.build(answer_params)
if @anwser.save
…
else
…
end
```

参考: [Railsガイド 4.3.1.14 collection.build(attributes = {}, ...)](http://railsguides.jp/association_basics.html#has-many%E3%81%A7%E8%BF%BD%E5%8A%A0%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B%E3%83%A1%E3%82%BD%E3%83%83%E3%83%89-collection-build-attributes)